# How to use live images on local install?

Tags: wp-config, configuration

How to use live images on a local WP install? I want to do something like the code down here in the `wp-config.php`. Problem is that the `siteurl` must be a relative path and cant be a url. I want to set up a local environment to test some parts offline and need to show the images.

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN'] == 'dev') {
  define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/siteurl.com/public_html/');
  define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/siteurl.com/public_html/');
  // use live images
  define( 'UPLOADS', 'http://siteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/' );
}
```

Comment: WordPress needs to save, delete, crop etc the images inside the upload folder. How can do it if it is in a different server and through the HTTP protocol? Why don't you just upload a few images just for testing?

Comment: I only need to display the images not to upload it locally. Its extra work and should be easy to use the live online images because they exist already its only an another url

Comment: I don't think uploading 2-3 photos will be that of an extra work. You don't need to upload them all.

Comment: Also you are confusing what is a URL and what is a path to a system folder.

Comment: but that's not my question ;) is it possible to set up an local environment like that? I can show a client a local version of a new feature for example and it would be nice if the images are shown

Comment: I understand your question. As far I know you can't do it like that. You can import your attachment to your local environment but still you have to copy your photos in your local upload folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to filter the output URLs temporarily to replace them with online images, using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', function ( $image, $attachment_id, $size ) {

    // For thumbnails
    if ( $size ) {
        switch ( $size ) {
            case 'thumbnail':
            case 'medium':
            case 'medium-large':
            case 'large':
                $image[0] = str_replace( 'localhost/', 'EXAMPLE.COM/', $image[0] );
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } else {
        $image[0] = str_replace( 'localhost/', 'EXAMPLE.COM/', $image[0] );
    }
    return $image;
}, 10, 3 );
```

This will replace any string containing `localhost` with your online domain's name. However, you can't modify or do anything with the image's, it's just for correcting the URL for development purposes.

Note that you should use the domain name without `http://` or any `/` before the domain's name.

Delete this function from your theme's `functions.php` after you are done with it.

Comment: This is working! But not all images urls are new, thumbnails are not working, is there also an solution for that?

Comment: hmm, i removed the `if()` to make sure everything works. How are the links to your thumbnails? still using localhost or totally broken after the code?

Comment: No broken code maybe it is because it are woocommerce images? are they use an another filter src?

Comment: I updated the answer for thumbnails. See if it works. Btw i haven't worked with wooCommerce yet. If you can tell me the function that renders the images, i can filter it for you.

Comment: Nope this version doesn't do anything, the previous is fine for now for me if you didn't have another update :D

Comment: That is strange. If you could copy a piece of your wooCommerce code that is generating the image ( the line that is outputting the image) i can update again for you.

Comment: I use timber maybe that's an issue. `{% if showthumb %}
            <div class="Media-figure {% if not post.thumbnail %}placeholder{% endif %}">
                <a href="{{post.link}}">
                    {% if post.thumbnail %}
                        <img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src|resize(post_thumb_size[0], post_thumb_size[1]) }}" />
                    {% else %}
                        <span class="thumb-placeholder"><i class="icon-camera"></i></span>
                    {% endif %}
                </a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}`

Answer (score 11):

The best way to do it is to use URL Rewrites.

This way you'll not have to do any change before uploading CODE to your server back again.

### Custom rules for `localhost`:

Try the following CODE in your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# custom rules for loading server images or any other uploaded media files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteRule ^.*/uploads/(.*)$ https://siteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# default WordPress rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Adjust your live domain to `siteurl.com` accordingly in the above code and your server images will be loaded when you develop from localhost.

Also, with this line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, the web server will check first if the image is available in your `localhost` (with the exact same name), and load from server only if it's not available locally. If you want to load server image even if that same image exists locally, then simply remove that line.

### Custom rules for non-production setup:

To implement the same for `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or any staging site, we can check if we're **not accessing the production site** and then set the rules for any other setup.

Assuming the production site's domain name is `siteurl.com`, `.htaccess` will look like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# custom rules for loading server images or any other uploaded media files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^siteurl.com$
RewriteRule ^.*/uploads/(.*)$ https://siteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# default WordPress rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In this solution, we've used the code `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^siteurl.com$` to check if we're not accessing the production site.

Comment: Idea looks good but not working for me with MAMP, some additional settings are needed?

Comment: You need to make sure `mod_rewrite` apache module is loaded and overridable from `.htaccess`

Comment: This should definitely be the correct answer. So good.

Comment: Instead of checking if it's local `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$`, I'd see if it's not production `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$` to account for staging environments.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked @scott answer to fit my needs with this variation:

```
# custom rules for loading server images or any other uploaded media files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads/[^\/]*/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://siteurl.com/$1 [QSA,L]
```